# sql limit записи с конца

Tags: php, база-данных, limit

Можно ли как-то получить n-количество записей из таблицы с конца с помощью limit, или может как-то по другом.

Comment: Делаете сортировку в обратном направлении и забираете первые n записей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В запрос добавьте типа этого.

```
 ORDER BY `sort`DESC LIMIT {count}
```

sort - значение по которому как бы сортирует в обратном порядке, значит последний элемент стане первым.

count - сколько записей вам надо